# BIG ISSUE - "Shopping Cart is empty" after ordering

Tags: cookie

Our site has been working fine, but a customer phoned today to let us know he couldn't buy. If you try and purchase any item on [www.medipost.shop](http://www.medipost.shop) you can add it to the shopping basket, but as soon as you click on the 'proceed to checkout' option, it presents you with

"Shopping Cart is Empty - You have no items in your shopping cart."

If you want to see the mistake, you need to :

1. Make an order on our webshop (and select "Virement bancaire" which
   means "Bank transfer", like that you can make an order without
   paying)
2. Then, return on the webshop, and try to add something to the shopping basket.
3. You will see the issue

I've been checking cookie settings, refreshing the index and following various guides to try and rectify this, but to no avail so far.

Would seriously appreciate any pointers here!

Thanks a lot for your help,

Alessandro

Comment: Can you check that the cart is actually empty on the back side, by checking the content of the quote and quote_item tables?
Do you have logs available for this problem?

Comment: There is a quote left with a reserved_order_id "000010453". This order has been placed by you right now. The quote contains same details, items_count = 1.
We found it with this querry " select * from quote where customer_firstname = 'GGG' "

Comment: When we clear the cache "PHPSESSID", all return to normal.

Here is the video of the problem : https://recordit.co/XG8Vt1PUEs

How can I fix that ?

Comment: No other quote associated to this customer ?

Comment: No, only this one.

Comment: Have you got some error log about add to cart on server side ?